# Disable drop down list items based on showed Data Table values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a page on which there are 2 items -

item - 1. Jquery DataTable that shows 2 column SystemName, System-Description.

item - 2. A small Form that has one dropdown and a text box. The dropdown contains System Names and the user enters some description in the textbox and inserts the value to DB . After inserting the value gets appeared in the Jquery Datatable .

As example in the Jquery datatable currently 3 values are presented. 
System1, System2 & System3.

In the DropdownList there are 7 items... System1, System2 ..... ,System7.

**What I Want to Achieve**

I want to disable the items in the DropDown List as per the datatable is shown.
So considering the previous example -

The items "System1, System2 & System3" should be disabled in the DropDownList.

**What I have tried** :

I tried with HTMLHelper extension as well . But it did not work.

This is how the Datatable and DDL are populated ::

**DropDownList** :

controller Code:

```
var flist = dbCtx.UserSystems.Where(l => l.InUse.Equals(false));
SelectList list = new SelectList(flist.ToList(), "SystemID", "SystemName");
ViewBag.sysnames = list;
```

Razor Code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SystemID, ViewBag.sysnames as SelectList, "Select SystemID", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**DataTable**:

controller Code:

```
SysViewModel.SysDetails = dbCtx.Get_UserSystem(Userid).ToList<Get_Get_UserSystem_Result>();
```

Razor Code:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="">
    <thead class="navbar-dark navbar-dark bg-blue-grey white">
        <tr>
            <th>
                System Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.SysDetails)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Desc)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the drop down option by the following way

```
<select>
    @{
        foreach (var item in List)
        {
            if(condition)//check exist or not
            {
            <option style="color:gray" disabled>
                @item.Name
            </option>
            }
            else
            {
            <option>
                @item.Name
            </option>
            }    
        }
    }
</select>
```